# Facebook link broken error by facebook reviewing the application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

I have upload the application in facebook for reviewing the application.
I have ask permission there in the facebook is email,basic profile, birthday,location,hometown. For login to my application i am login to facebook through default setting of the iphone.
The facebook review team send me this kind of status after the review can anybody help me to solve this.
I have already seen the facebook documentation for permission so please don't put link of the facebook documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: app id is correct and it is working in iphone but the facebook reject the application because of the above reason

Comment: You can file a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs and someone at Facebook can help you resolve this.

Comment: I have done resolve the issue by uploading ipa from the one my friend in usa and the facebook approve the application.